# Word Formula for "issue date + 3 months"

Tags: ms-word, formula, excel-formula

Is there a word formula we can apply in a document to automatically calculate:

```
"Issue Date + 3 months = Resultant Date"
```

So for example: if the issue date of a document was `1 July 2011`, the output should be `1 October 2011`.

Comment: I don't see `Issue Date` as any of the available properties of a Word or Excel document. Where would it come from?

Comment: @KenWhite I think what OP means is if there is something like a bookmark holding a date, can another bookmark do a calculation based on that date.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this. Dates can be calculated with VBA using field codes, bookmarks, or forms.

Greg Maxey has done a fantastic job explaining all three approaches (along with providing code samples) here:

http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/calculated_dates.html